# Binary search tree in C++ with leaves as null values not working with reference parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference

Im trying to write a simple function to decide in a binary tree is also a binary search tree as a way to learn C++. However the first problem I found was to define the end leafs in my recursive `Node struct`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
Node CreateNode(const int data, const Node& left, const Node& right) {
    Node node;
    node.data = data;
    node.left -> left;
    node.right -> right;
    return node;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    auto root = CreateNode(1, NULL, NULL);
    isBST(&root);

    return 0;
}

bool isBST(Node* root) {

}
```

A solution would be to use pointers instead as parameters to CreateNode but I dont want to do that since C++11 recommends to replace pointer parameters with reference parameters.

My questions is how can I define leaves in my code above since I cant just make them null pointers as I would if my parameters would have been pointers.

Update:
The isBST has a parameter as pointer only because I want to mix it up to understand the difference.

Comment: What exactly is `node.left -> left;` supposed to achieve?

Comment: The "replace pointers with references" advice applies when the purpose is to pass the thing that the pointer points to, either because you don't want to copy it or because you want to modify it. When the pointer *is* the thing you want to pass, you pass the pointer.

Comment: `node.left -> left;` suggests that you may have rushed through the first chapters of your book and need to revise the fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References are not really suitable in this context because they imply no ownership transfer and no optional supply. Another approach will be to use smart pointers.

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct Node;

using UniqueNode = ::std::unique_ptr<Node>;

struct Node 
{
   int data;
   UniqueNode left;
   UniqueNode right;

   explicit Node(void): data{} {}

   explicit Node(int const init_data, UniqueNode init_left, UniqueNode init_right)
   :   data{init_data}
   ,   left{::std::move(init_left)}
   ,   right{::std::move(init_right)}
   {}
};

// no need to manually write create function...
// UniqueNode CreateNode(const int data, UniqueNode left, UniqueNode right) 

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   UniqueNode root{::std::make_unique<Node>(42, nullptr, nullptr)};
   isBST(*root);

  return 0;
}

// takes a reference because no ownership is transferred, probably should be a member funciton
bool isBST(Node & root) {

}
```

Comment: could you expand on this comment "ownership transfer and no optional supply"

Comment: @user3139545 If you use reference as a parameter then there is no way to take ownership of the passed value to make it a leaf of the node for example. If you use reference as a parameter then there is no way to supply "empy" or "null" value because reference must be bound to the existing object.

Comment: Ok it is this part i dont understand "optional supply" what do you mean by optional supply, what is meant by supply in this context?

Comment: @user3139545 That part is described in the second sentence of my previous comment.